# How can I await AssetBundle.LoadAssetAsync?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Task<AssetBundle> request = assetbundles.LoadBundleAsync(bundleName); 
await request;
AssetBundleRequest req = request.Result.LoadAssetAsync<T>(assetPath);
await req; //that's wrong
return req.asset as T;
```

await is easy use in Task field. how can I use await in non-task field ?

Comment: `await` is used to await already executing asynchronous operations, not fields or arbitrary types. `request` isn't a field, it's a `Task` that represents an asynchronous operation. Its result is the result of the operation, which means there's *no* reason to use `request.Result`. You should have used `var req=await assetbundles.LoadBundleAsync(bundleName);`

Comment: To use `await`, the class needs to implement `INotifyCompletion` which in turn exposes `bool IsCompleted { get; }`, `void OnCompleted(Action continuation);`, `TResult GetResult();` ... `AssetBundleRequest` has none of those things, however unity is a bit strange the way it does things

Answer (score 4):

[`AssetBundle.LoadAssetAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadAssetAsync.html) returns an [`AssetBundleRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundleRequest.html) which is **not a `Task`**!

It rather inherits from [`AsyncOperation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation.html) which is a [`YieldInstruction`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/YieldInstruction.html) to be used and `yield`ed inside of a [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html).

You can see a demonstration of how it is used inside Unity in the example of [`AssetBundle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html). Coroutines have to be started (via [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)) and running in the Unity **main thread** so anyway you will have to dispatch the result after the first `await` back into the main thread.

Additionally most of the Unity API also only may be used on the Unity maint hread! The exception are basically only the pure mathematical structs like `Vector3` etc.

You could however move the entire thing into a `Coroutine` and do

```
private IEnumerator Load<T>(string bundleName, string assetPath, Action<T> onFinished)
{
    var request = assetbundles.LoadBundleAsync(bundleName); 
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => request.IsCompleted);

    if(request.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"LoadBundleAsync for \"{bundleName}\" failed!");
    }

    var req = request.Result.LoadAssetAsync<T>(assetPath);
    yield return req;

    onFinished?.Invoke(req.asset as T);
}
```

This can now be started as a Coroutine using

```
StartCoroutine(Load<GameObject>("someBundle", "some/path/inside"), OnFinishedLoading);

...

private void OnFinsihedLoading(GameObject obj)
{
    Instantiate(obj);
}
```

Do give a more precise answer we would need more of your context.

Comment: it's good way, but my class is not inherit monoBehaviour. maybe I should think about how to modify my class

Comment: It doesn't need to inherit from `MonoBehaviour` ... you can pass in a reference to the `MonoBehaviour` that originally calls this and then use `thatMonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine`

Comment: got it, thank you solution, I will try solve problem.